# Detect relation between two persons in text

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

Goal is to find all the pairs of persons between which there is *any* kind of relation in a piece of text. Particularly, if we have this piece of text:

> Alice Wilson, doctor with more than 30 years of experience in suppressing virus epidemics, has met with the president of Neverland
>   country, John Doe, to discuss ways of tackling a new virus.
>
> John Doe will meet next week with the state official Jack Sparrow of some other country to discuss something
>   totally-unrelated-to-the-first-part-of-text.

There is a relation between `Alice Wilson` and `John Doe`, as well as `John Doe` and `Jack Sparrow`. However, there is no real relation between `Alice Wilson` and `Jack Sparrow`, apart from that they both appear in the same text.

Therefore, the resulting pairs would be:

```
Alice Wilson, John Doe
John Doe, Jack Sparrow
```

I have found a way to extract people's names from text using Stanford CoreNLP's Named Entity Recognizer, thus having `Alice Wilson`, `John Doe` and `Jack Sparrow`, but I am not sure how to find relations between them. CoreNLP can perform Part-of-Speech tagging, which can tag words with `Subject`, `Verb`, `Object` etc. Nonetheless, I still don't see a way of tackling all the possible variations where a person's name can be found, e.g.:

```
John Doe said that... <- 'John Doe' is a Subject
Jack Sparrow introduced John Doe to the senior officials... <- 'John Doe' is an Object
Jack Sparrow, John Doe's cousin, told the press... <- Not even sure what 'John Doe' here is.
```

Any ideas (code is welcome, but not necessary) on how to approach this?

Comment: As long as they are in the same sentence, it is quite researched and possible. See the answer from @Sonal Gupta. But if you by "a piece of text" means an entity spanning over more than a sentence and with synonyms and more difficult relations it will be a harder problem. Consider this:  "Jane doe is the presidents wife. Jack Sparrow has spent a lot of time in the company of the first lady."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see if there's a dependency path between the two entities in the sentence. For more info: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml

It won't be 100% accurate but good enough. To improve accuracy, you can prune the paths that are longer than certain lengths or have certain dependencies.

You can also look at open information extraction tools like http://reverb.cs.washington.edu

Comment: I've looked into the dependency graph. However, isn't there a dependency path between every two nodes in the graph? Could you please give an example of two edges being on the same path and two that are not?

Comment: Yes; depending on your problem you can prune on what kinds of paths are acceptable. For example, not consider paths that have rcmod. In the sentence: "Eva is married to John, who was previously married to Elane.", Eva and Elane would be connected only through rcmod. My guess is that ReVerb is better suited for your needs. It builds on Stanford like dependencies. PS: you can try out the Stanford tool at http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process